# Session expires even doing operations on pop up Window (Window.open)

Tags: jsp, servlets

On our Application , We have HyPer Links on our Grid .(Result Display)
On click of that a new Pop Up Window is opened , using window.open pop up mechanism 
We can do several operations on that newly opened window like Insertion , Deletion ,Updation of data with respect to DataBase .

The issue is that , even though we are doing several  operations on our Database , the session is being expired on to the Application .

Please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: It should not behave like that, unless cookies are not accepted by your browser and the session falls back to URL rewriting (and you don't use encodeURL on all your hyperlinks to make sure the sesion ID is written in the URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy to provide an answer. It highly depends on your environment. Maybe your application server does not only rely on JSESSIONID, it may use cookies provided by a certain SingleSignOn  system. Those cookies may have a fixed lifetime. Trace your HTTP requests / responses using Firefox Firebug or WebKit (Chrome) developer tools and check which cookies are exchanged. If necessary define a javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener and track the application server's behaviour.